# Want to activate my account to deploy Vosao CMS on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, content-management-system

I want to deploy Vosao from appcfg.sh. I never knew I have to
activate my account before executing the script for deployment. Prior to that for other GAE apps I used to deploy my app from Eclipse plugin.

http://appengine.google.com/promo/java_runtime 
On this page I have following message.

> Thanks for signing up. Once your account is activated, you will
>   receive an email with more information.

When my account will be activated so that I can deploy my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've somehow stumbled onto the page for when - years ago - the Java runtime was still in Trusted Tester. That isn't the case anymore, and you don't need to wait for your account to be activated - you can use it immediately.

Comment: I was getting 500 error while running the appcfg.sh script to deploy on the server. Dont want to use Eclipse plugin for deployment. I dont know the reason for this. When I googled about the error, comes up that it needs my gmail email address to activate. You are making sense. But I dont know, whatt the actual problem is.